# Мгновенный повтор RTSP-потока

Tags: c#, rtsp

Как мне хранить последние 15 (условно) секунд, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Запись" запись началась за 15 секунд до нажатия кнопки. Как это реализовано в мгновенном повторе от NVidia.

По сути это в буфер надо перезаписывать поток. Но не уверен, в правильную сторону ли я мыслю

Comment: Зависит от того как, чем, и что вы получаете. Например, вот пример [некой библиотеки](https://github.com/BogdanovKirill/RtspClientSharp/blob/cd7170f1eeb98f8ae0fb9d85ee044a7357eeee11/Examples/MjpegSnapshotsMaker/Program.cs#L78), которая отдает в ответ вам массив байт под каждый кадр, со смещением и прочим, вам достаточно это сохранять в массив и в случае если там условно больше 100 кадров - удаляем самый старый, ну а в момент сохранения, собираем все кадры и пишем куда надо, готово.